# Redirect a specific page from http to https in wordpress .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I need to redirect only one page in my wordpress site from http to https. I searched online but none of the solutions seem to work. This is the code I have in my .htaccess file:

```
# Redirect to force SSL on test page
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^test/$ https://www.example.com/test/ [R=301,L]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure those rules are above all the wordpress rules in your htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin called "page links to"

It adds a meta box to the bottom of the post/page and you can tell it "point to other URL" instead of "Point to existing url". It then gives you a box to put any URL in there you'd like. I presume, you'd be able to redirect to https:// since we've used it for years to redirect to many different places (though not specifically an https version of the page). It's a free plugin though, and I don't see why it wouldn't work

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to do this without using any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^my-test-page\.html$ https://www.domain.com/my-test-page.html [R=301,L]
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

edit `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```